# apache tomcat file download only after session authentication jsp

Tags: apache, jsp, authentication, tomcat, download

Hi
i am using apache tomcat.
i have a jsp file for entering user name and password and a java bean for authentication.
after user have been authenticated i create a session variable with the user name and another by the name of "authenticated" with the value true.
i want to allow file download only after the session variable "authentication" == true;
i also want to do some processing before the download (registering the user name who downloaded..)

the problem:
lets say i have the file "download.bin" inside directory "/downloads"
so anyone who go directly to url "downloads/download.bin" will get the file.

1.can i prevent direct download of the file 
2. enable the file download only after session authentication.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent the file from being directly downloaded. One common way to do that would be to put your `/downloads` folder inside of the `WEB-INF`. Create a servlet which checks your authentication flag and then sends the file to the user.
A users request may look something like the following:

```
http://localhost/myApp/downloadServlet?filename=download.bin
```

Since content inside the WEB-INF is not available publicly, you can hide your files there.