# Jnlp-Prevent downloading of the jars that i referenced

Tags: java, jar, reference, jnlp

I have been developed a jnlp file, and it is working properly when client downloads it from his/her browser. No problem up to here, but client can also access to the jar files that my jnlp is referencing, and eventually download them.

I don't want my jars to be downloaded by others by writing the path from browser. I just want to make the jnlp is directly accessible from browser.

How can I fix this situation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the provided JnlpDownloadServlet as a way to block access.  The JnlpDownloadServlet (look for it in the samples provided with the JDK) will handle requests for Jar files and do a diff on them.  If you setup your web.xml file like

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JnlpDownloadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.javaws.servlet.JnlpDownloadServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JnlpDownloadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

then all requests for the files in /app will go through this servlet.  This will prevent users from doing a simple browse to see the available files, but if they know the file name they can still create a get request to fetch it through the servlet.

If that is a problem, then you can also put security on access to this servlet (as you would any other servlet) using the **security-constraint** settings in the web.xml.  If you add that, then the javaws launcher will require the user to provide valid credentials before it will download the files.  I used BASIC as the **auth-method** because I wasn't sure if the javaws client would honor any others.

Answer (score 3):

There is no 'fix' for it.  If the Jars are accessible to the JWS client that launches the app., they are also available by direct fetch.

Answer (score 0):

What if you generate the jnlp dynamically via a JSP or servlet (see here an [example](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wsdoc400/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.iseries.doc/info/ae/ae/ccli_jnlp.html))?

In this case you can write a filter that can implement a policy(based on a cookie?) for retrieving files. If the cookie is not set you can disable the download of jars.

See the following [article: http://lopica.sourceforge.net/faq.html#cookies](http://lopica.sourceforge.net/faq.html#cookies)

Comment: This seems beneficial. While looking for a way, a friend said me a method. Here it is: What if i create a dummy webProject, put all stuff (jnlp and jars) in this project, and use the web.xml for preventing my jars to be downloaded with direct access. Is it really possible, if so how ? Could you give an example ?

Comment: See this - it is somehow related:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662288/apache-tomcat-file-download-only-after-session-authentication-jsp

Comment: A simpler solution is to check for "User-Agent" and forbid downloads if it is not JNLP. For how a filter works see:http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-tomcat2/