# Continue Browser Session in JNLP Java Web Start while maintaining jar cache

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat7, java-web-start, jnlp

The user is authenticated in the browser and then a JNLP is launched to launch application in Java Web Start. We want to be able to restrict the jar downloads to only authenticated users.

One idea was to use an authentication token in the url for the jars so that we only serve jars to authenticated users. The problem with doing this is the web start clients will redownload the jars each time since the url will change.

Is there a way to pass the JSESSIONID to jnlp and pass it as a cookie for each jar request like a browser does?

Comment: Why would the url change each time? You could generate the same token for the same user every time.

Comment: The base url would stay the same, we would have a parameter containing the token. This seems to cause Jws to redownload the jars.

Comment: Even if the token is the same every time? Another way would be to put the token as part of the path instead of a parameter, if it's correctly mapped you can still handle it in a servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8331192/488012

It involves using [Security Constraints](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncbe.html#bncbk)

Then JWS will ask for credentials when downloading the jars.

Comment: One thing we don't want to do is ask for credentials more than once. So we want a users who has a valid web session to be able to download the jnlp and start up the client application without providing credentials a second time.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the <s>droids</s> answer you're looking for, but have you ever thought of adding login credentials to the app itself? So when the app launches a login screen is displayed? Then you can store the credentials with `Preferences` and whatnot. Then you won't care who downloads your app, it will be secure from the inside.